# calendarextender causing postback in Opera when using with master page

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, opera, calendarextender

I am having a very wired problem with calendar extender from ajax control toolkit in Opera. It's working fine in Chrome but in OPERA when I click on the image button to open calendar it will causing a post back and page get refreshed (calendar isn't opening).

If the page is simple page its working but if its a content page from a master page then the problem is there (for Opera).

Comment: Hi, can you give me a link to a page that shows this problem, or maybe a demo page for the calendar script you're using? There is *NO* way we can help you with this problem unless we can have a look at it.

Comment: Hi hallvors, I had added links for demo page.. please have a look.

Comment: Hi, I get resolved the issue.. I was missing a javascript function which is called from server side and bind to scriptmanager.

thanks for help.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I resolved the issue. I was missing a JavaScript function which is called from server side and bind to scriptmanager.